# Is there a way to render SVG objects on HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

My program generates SVG objects dynamically and I can visualise them by adding them to the DOM.

I would also like to draw them on a HTML5 canvas but so far have failed despite lost of searching on the web. Support for drawing SVGs that are actual source files is abundant but not for dynamically created SVGs as far as I can find so far.

My attempts are shown in the code below:

```
// dynamically create an svg containing a black circle
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS (svgns, "svg");
svg.setAttribute ( "width"  , "128" );
svg.setAttribute ( "height" , "128" );
svg.setAttributeNS ("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

shape = document.createElementNS (svgns, "circle"); 
svg.appendChild (shape);
shape.setAttribute ( "cx", 64);
shape.setAttribute ( "cy", 64);
shape.setAttribute ( "r",  50);
shape.setAttribute ( "fill", "black");

// add the svg to the DOM
document.body.appendChild (svg); // works

// create a canvas to render the black circle
var canvas = document.createElement ("canvas"); 
document.body.appendChild (canvas);
canvas.width = 300 ; canvas.height = 150 ;
var ctx = canvas.getContext ("2d");
// create an image to contain the svg data
var img = new Image ();
img.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage (this,10,10) }; 

// ATTEMPT 1

var svgURL = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString (svg);
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent (svgURL);  // does not work

// ATTEMPT 2

var xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString (svg);
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa (xml); //  also does not work

// ATTEMPT 3

var hiddenDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
hiddenDiv.appendChild (svg.cloneNode(true));
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa (hiddenDiv.innerHTML); // also deos not work
```

By the way in case you ask why not draw the object directly onto the canvas instead of creating the SVG, it is that I want to use the svgs in the DOM as well.

Comment: have a look at fabricjs

Comment: Only by reading it, the only error I see in your code is the xlink nameSpace resolver. But you don't even need this attribute, so don't set it.

Comment: And actually even with this error, your first attempt works fine on both my FF and chrome on Android. https://jsfiddle.net/1by04Lb5/ What browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome for testing

Comment: This is puzzling. I have now tried my first attempt again and it works. MY apologies for wasting your time. Regarding the error you mentioned, do I just remove that line of code, or the xlink parameter?

Comment: I have now established why it did not initially work. The example I added above was cut down slightly. The difference was that I had set the fill to be a url to an externally defined gradient (in another svg) and this apparently does not work.

Comment: Since this is in html, you don't need to set any xmlns resolvers. Your xmlSerializer will add it for you at extract. And since I didn't precised what was the error exactly it should be `../1999/..` not 2000. But once again, you don't need this `xmlns:xlink` attribute.

Comment: Ah then it'an entirely other problem: svg documents in `<img>` tags can't load any external resources, you would have to include this external resource directly in your svg node. And there tenth of dupes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159139/discussion-between-steve-brooker-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) library does what you're after.

From the introduction text:

> canvg is a SVG parser and renderer. It takes a URL to a SVG file or the text of an SVG file, parses it in JavaScript, and renders the result on a Canvas element. The rendering speed of the examples is about as fast as native SVG.

I used it a while ago and found it straightforward to use and reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I was about to go there next, but had been hoping for something easier.

Comment: No problem. Yes, something easier would be nice, but I don't know of any way to do it without a library or an equivalent bulk of code.

Comment: canvg is okay for simple things, but bare in mind that it requires *all* CSS affecting the SVG to be inline or it will be ignored (At least it did when I last used it)

Comment: Interesting. Makes sense I suppose. That was fine in my case. It might not work in your case, but you could always layer the SVG on top of the canvas, so long as you don't need to draw both below and on top of the SVG elements. I'm sure you've considered that though.

Comment: Thanks also that it is good to know that it was straightforward to use and reliable, before I get started. Do you know whether it supports url refs to defs (such as linear gradients) defined in other svgs? Do you know whether it is likely to work on older browsers (such as mobile safari in UIwebview?)

Comment: layering onto of the canvas will not work in my case. My canvas is a map, the SVGs are icons on the map. I need to be able to pan and zoom the map quickly (as canvas does nicely) and I need to be able to draw possibly hundreds of overlapping icons

Comment: I was building a map too :) But my case was constrained to Chrome and pretty simple SVG elements. It shouldn't be too hard to test external defs.